# how do you install SSIS on a cluster environment

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis

I'm running SQL Server 2005 enterprise edition on a 2 node active-active cluster windows 2003 server.  I go to add/remove programs, click on SQL Server and then the link for "to install a new component, click here".  It then says enter the location.  Where do I go to find SSIS add-on from here?

Is SQL Server Integration Services offered on the SQL Server Installation dvd or is this something I need to download?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSIS is on the SQL 2005 installation disk. To install it, just pop the disk in and start the installation wizard. You can then install SSIS as a package, and just make sure you don't tick any of the database engines, or else you'll get another SQL instance installed!

Comment: Do I need to do anything special because it is being installed on a cluster server?  I'm assuming I should stop all sql server services before installing the SSIS add-on?

Comment: Honestly, I've no idea, because I'm not the DBA for our clustered servers, only our stand-alones!

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the cluster...

This article might be helpful:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345193.aspx

There are some special notes (problems) in there about trying to cluster integration services in an a/a cluster.  Integration services will not run more than one instance on a machine, so when it fails over an tries to start up, it will fail, potentially affecting the group.

Microsoft does not recommend that the Integration Services service be configured as a cluster resource.

"The Integration Services service supports the administrative interface in SQL Server Management Studio for listing, starting, stopping, monitoring, importing, and exporting Integration Services packages. The Integration Services service is not required to design packages. The Integration Services service is also not required to run packages, or to schedule SQL Server Agent jobs that run packages."